# how can I populate this table with the each() method using jquery

Tags: jquery, each

Im trying to iterate this process..using the for-loop method in jquery (each();) but I cant make it happen. Any idea how I could create more 'rows' everytime I adding more carItems without doing it manually? thanks!

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>  </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="cart">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Qty.</th>
                <th>Total</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr class="template" style="display:none;">
              <td><span class="item_name">Name</span></td>
              <td><span class="item_qty">Quantity</span></td>
              <td><span class="item_total">Total</span>.00</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    </body>

    </html>

    function template(row, cart) {
      row.find('.item_name').text(cart.name);
      row.find('.item_qty').text(cart.qty);
      row.find('.item_total').text(cart.total);
      return row;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var newRow = $('#cart .template').clone().removeClass('template');
        var newRow_1 = $('#cart .template').clone().removeClass('template');



      var cartItem = 
      {
        name: 'Glendatronix',
        qty: 1,
        total: 450
      };

       var cartItem_1 = {
        name: 'Glendatronix',
        qty: 1,
        total: 450
      };


      template(newRow, cartItem)
        .appendTo('#cart')
        .fadeIn(); 

          template(newRow_1, cartItem_1)
        .appendTo('#cart')
        .fadeIn();   
    });
```

Comment: Are you asking for a loop that iterates through x amounts of cartitems and appends them to the cart?

Comment: @johan yes and at the same time to create those rows for every carItem...?  :( I guess I need to change the whole idea so far?

Comment: I've added some basic code for a loop that might get you on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tmpl = $('#cart .template').clone();    

var template = function(cart) {
    var html = tmpl;
    html.find('.item_name').text(cart.name);
    html.find('.item_qty').text(cart.qty);
    html.find('.item_total').text(cart.total);
    return html.html();
}


var cart = [
{
  name: 'Glendatronix 1',
  qty: 1,
  total: 450
},{
  name: 'Glendatronix 2',
  qty: 1,
  total: 450
}];


$.each(cart, function(item) {
   $('#cart').append('<tr>' + template(cart[item]) + '</tr>' );
});
```

So basically, have your cart summary in an array. Loop through this array, take basic template and modify it with data. But change it with how template should work in my last comment, i don't like my tricks i added :-)

Comment: hi there! when I run the code, the console tells me that the template isnot a function at this row: $('#cart').append( template(cart[item]) ).fadeIn();
 any idea why?

Comment: I made some changes at the end: "$(cart).each( function(item) {
 

  template(cart[item]).appendTo('#cart ').fadeIn(500) ;
});" cuz u wanna append the result to the table right!? the thing is I just can see the last item not all the items? any idea

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NkRhv/1/ I used Mark's fiddle, just run it and see that template is outside javascript (were it belongs) but inside a tag specially for js templating and simply using replace functionallity instead of making a fragment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NkRhv/2/ now i push cart items to array, this is better then appending per item if lot of items will be there. I guess i like this setup more, now enjoy making your own stuff :-)

Comment: And if you want framework for it look at backbone and underscore, very cool if you are more familiair with it http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

Answer (score 1):

```
var cartItems = 
[
    {
        name: 'Glendatronix',
        qty: 1,
        total: 450
    },
    {
        name: 'Glenda',
        qty: 2,
        total: 451
    }
];

$(function(){

     $.each(cartItems, function(){

         var $tr = $('<tr/>')
             .html('<td>' +  this.name + '</td>'); //add names, quantity etc here...
             .appendTo('#cart');

     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this solution here. It also uses clone from the jquery and appends the item.

http://jsfiddle.net/L89kw/5

BTW: It was important to add the `.fadeIn()` (i used `animate({opacity: 1})` in the sample) *after* appending the element to the table. Did not read the documentation, but I think, that append doesn't return the new element (at least not in jquery 1.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Clone is nice, but you can take the next step and use somthing like handlebars http://handlebarsjs.com/ I had good experience with it

Another alternative JQUERY template plugin http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Or knockout.js that has bigger affect on your code as being a wider framework.

Comment: thanks for dat, I already tried handlebarsjs which I find very easy...I just want to try and learn other ways... :)